# trying to get button to appear over img button on scrollover

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a button appear over a image on scroll over.

````
<a class="portfolio-box" href="https://samuellutz.github.io/Sound-Lane/" title="Sound-Lane">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="assets/img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="sound-lane" />
                            <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                                <div class="project-category text-white-50"></div>
                                <div class="project-name">Sound Lane
                                    <button class="btn-primary btn button" href="https://github.com/samuellutz/Sound-Lane" class="">github</button>
                                    <p>A music artist search website.</p>
                                    <p>Built with HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Glider.js, and API.</p>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>```

i'm trying to make the button clickable once you scroll over and make it appear.
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://samuellutz.github.io/Portfolio-new/ is the link to the portfolio area links to the site but not the github even though the button is there is wont let you click on it